# How to replace text in the middle of a url string with regex.replace in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have this string [seen here](http://media.rtv.net/image/201410/w460/loc_crima_lac_67711100.jpg) and I want it to become something [like this](http://media.rtv.net/image/201410/full/loc_crima_lac_67711100.jpg).

I have tried regex with *w460, (w460), w.0 but nothing works

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? can you just do something like `id="w460"; newUrl = url.replace("/"+id+"/", "/full/")`

Comment: What are the expected input strings? The answers given below should work fine for the given example, but if they're "not working" it's because your question is not precise enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you dont use `Replace` ?

```
var fullUrl = originalurl.Replace("w460", "full");
```

With regex:

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("w460"));
var webString = regex.Replace(@"http://media.rtv.net/image/201410/w460/loc_crima_lac_67711100.jpg", "full", 1);
```

this will replace the first "w460" text

Comment: This won't work if there are any other `w460` in this string.

Comment: thanks, i just tried and it did not work. my string still looks like this <img src=http://media.rtv.net/image/201410/w460/loc_crima_lac_67711100.jpg width="100%" id="main_img"/>

Comment: @ventura8 then looks like something else is wrong to stop it using the fullUrl. How do you get from generating the url to showing it in an `img`? You probably need to post more code to give some context

Comment: after i generate the string i use webBrowser.NavigateToString(webString);

Comment: It WORKS, i am sorry for earlier. I did not look at the right string :). Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://media.rtv.net/image/201410/w460/loc_crima_lac_67711100.jpg";
url = url.Replace("/w460/", "/full/");
```

Use the Replace method of string.

I would't recommend using regex here, it just adds a bit of extra overhead in your code. Creating another instance of an object just to replace a single string occurence? The `Replace` method of String is ok for this situation, plus it's more readable this way.

Comment: How can this won't work? Have you tried it? The result is http://media.rtv.net/image/201410/full/loc_crima_lac_67711100.jpg.
just copied out from my console.. And navigated there.. So?

Answer (score 0):

The solution actually depends. What is "w460" a constant or pattern? You can make like below or there could be much more patterns to match the best requieremens

```
var input = @"http://media.rtv.net/image/201410/w460/loc_crima_lac_67711100.jpg";
var pattern = @"w\d{3}";
var replacement = "full";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: var pattern = @"/\D{1}\d{3}/";
var replacement = "/full/"; // to make it more generic